# Why does String implicitly convert to &str in Rust?

Tags: string, rust

Considering the following code:

```
let s = String::from("hello");
let mut r = String::new();

for c in s.chars() {
    r.push(c);
}
```

As `chars` is the method of `&str`, why can `String` call it? I suppose it has something to do with the `coercion`, but I don't fully understand this implicit conversion.

Comment: The exact explanation is in the [String documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#deref).

Comment: @edwardw I know that it can convert `&String` to `&str`, but here it does not get the reference of `s`.

Comment: @chenzhongpu "When looking up a method call, the receiver may be automatically dereferenced or borrowed in order to call a method." (https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html)

Comment: got it @DenysSéguret

Comment: See also the longer Deref coercion explanation in the book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods

Comment: Does [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing  rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules) answer your question?

Comment: @trentclt No, in this case, it is caused by both auto-reference (in the first step) and coercion (in the second step)

Answer (score 2):

This is actually covered in this question:
[What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules). There is a lot going on in that answer, so I will try to apply it to your question.

To quote huon's answer:

> The core of the algorithm is:
>
> - For each ["dereference step"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b6d91a2bdac45cd919497a24207fab843124d4ba/src/librustc_typeck/check/method/probe.rs#L166-L196) `U` (that is, set `U = T` and then `U = *T`, ...)
>
>   1. if there's a method `bar` where the receiver type (the type of `self` in the method) matches `U` exactly , use it ([a "by value method"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b6d91a2bdac45cd919497a24207fab843124d4ba/src/librustc_typeck/check/method/probe.rs#L793))
>   2. otherwise, add one auto-ref (take `&` or `&mut` of the receiver), and, if some method's receiver matches `&U`, use it ([an "autorefd method"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b6d91a2bdac45cd919497a24207fab843124d4ba/src/librustc_typeck/check/method/probe.rs#L798))

The key is in the "dereference steps": `U = *T` means `let u = Deref::deref(t);`, where `u: U`, `t: T`. We keep doing that until something can't be dereferenced any more.

Following that algorithm for the call to `s.chars()` from your code:

1. First dereference step (no deref):

   1. Can you call `String::chars(s)`? *No.*
   2. What about `&String` or `&mut String`? *No.*
2. Second dereference step: `<String as Deref>::Target = str`, so we are looking for methods of `str`. `let c: str = *s` (assuming this DST type was allowed);

   1. Can you call `str::chars(c)`? *No*.
   2. Can you call `str::chars(&c)`? *Yes!*