# Confusion over auto-dereferencing rules when using function

Tags: rust

Assume we already know that `String` can become `&str` after deref for

```rust
impl ops::Deref for String {
    type Target = str;

    #[inline]
    fn deref(&self) -> &str {
        unsafe { str::from_utf8_unchecked(&self.vec) }
    }
}
```

- This code can work because there is a deref chain: `&String --> String ---> &str`.

  ```rust
  fn uppercase(s: &str) -> String {
      s.to_uppercase()
  }

  fn main() {
      let s = String::from("hello");
      assert_eq!(uppercase(&s), "HELLO");
  }
  ```
- Why does the code below not work even though there is a deref chain `String ---> &str`?

  ```rust
  fn uppercase(s: &str) -> String {
      s.to_uppercase()
  }

  fn main() {
      let s = String::from("hello");
      assert_eq!(uppercase(s), "HELLO");
  }
  ```
- Why does the code below not work even though there is a deref chain: `&String --> String`?

  ```rust
  fn uppercase(s: String) -> String {
      s.to_uppercase()
  }

  fn main() {
      let s = String::from("hello");
      assert_eq!(uppercase(&s), "HELLO");
  }
  ```

### Reference

- [Why does String implicitly convert to &str in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58023943/why-does-string-implicitly-convert-to-str-in-rust)
- [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules)

Comment: From the word dereference alone, then being able to dereference _requires_ a reference, which you don't provide in "code 2". I'm not sure what you mean in "code 3", you can't `deref()` a `&String` into a `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods):

> *Deref coercion* is a convenience that Rust performs on arguments to functions and methods. Deref coercion works only on types that implement the `Deref` trait. Deref coercion converts such a type into a reference to another type. For example, deref coercion can convert `&String` to `&str` because `String` implements the `Deref` trait such that it returns `&str`. Deref coercion happens automatically when we pass a reference to a particular type’s value as an argument to a function or method that doesn’t match the parameter type in the function or method definition. A sequence of calls to the `deref` method converts the type we provided into the type the parameter needs.

Deref coercion converts references into references. It will auto-deref `&value` to `&*value`, `&**value`, `&***value`, etc., in order to convert one reference type into another that fits a parameter signature. The starting and ending types are always references.

Notably, it doesn't put the deref on the front. It doesn't do `&value` to `*&value` to `**&value`, which is why it won't convert `&String` to `String` or `String` to `&str`.

- Turning `&String` into `String` would turn it into a move. If I wrote `func(&s)` and `func` takes a `String` it would be confusing if that compiled and actually moved `s`.
- Similarly, turning `String` into `&str` would turn a move into a pass-by-reference. If I wrote `func(s)` I'd expect `s` to be moved, with ownership transferred to `func`. It should not compile if `func` takes a `&str` and I pass a `String`.

Comment: In this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58023943/why-does-string-implicitly-convert-to-str-in-rust), one can transfer `String` to `&str` in receiver type by deref. So auto deref rule of receiver in method is different from argument in function?

Comment: @gaoxinge Yes, [determining the type of the receiver is a completely different mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53344847).

Comment: Oh, shoot, I... somehow missed that was a quote? I must have been sleepy. Good point. I'll take another stab at it later I guess